# How can you make the output of a key dependent on the duration which it is pressed. (in ahk, Autohotkey)

Tags: autohotkey

Basically what I want is the <kbd>F9</kbd> key to be transformed into <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> when it is pressed for under 500ms and into <kbd>Esc</kbd> for any duration above 500ms.
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$F9::
Keywait, F9, T0.5 ; waits 0.5 seconds maximally for F9 to be released
if ErrorLevel     ; pressed for above that time
     Send ^w
else
     Send {Esc}
Return
```

or

```
$F9::
Keywait, F9, T0.5 ; waits 0.5 seconds maximally for F9 to be released
if ErrorLevel     ; pressed for above that time
{
     KeyWait, F9  ; wait for F9 to be released
     Send ^w    
}
else
     Send {Esc}
Return
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm

Comment: For some reason it always immediatly sends Esc and not ^w, I dont know why :(  I also tried Errorlevel=0 or =1 and I also made brackets around if (expression) {statement} but to no avail.

Comment: Try also the second code in the edited answer in a stand alone script (use only the above code in the script and close all other scripts that may interfere).